# How does one evaluate a number raised to decimal/ fraction exponent?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Determine a way of evaluating  $x^{\frac1n}$
>
> Case 1: n is integer
>
> Case 2: n is a real number
>
> No Calculus, or series allowed!

Suppose you have  $2^{\frac14}$ then is there some rule to evaluate for it as a number plus some decimal expansion.

Exponent of natural integer are easy to evaluate as they are just repeated multiplication but I can't see how to extend this idea to evaluate in case of fractional/ decimal power.

---

After reading comments, I actually confess I did not know that you needed calculus for the proper construction of these numbers. In school, we often learn surds like square roots and cube roots way before calculus ever begins. Hence, I was of the thought that maybe there would be non calculus methods to calculate the above.

Comment: What is the point of forbidding basically all methods with which we can determine a number like $2^{\frac{1}{4}}$ ?

Comment: If you know the manual square root algorithm, you can take the square root twice, but that wouldn't help with $2^{1/7}$, say.  Why these artificial restrictions.  Without calculus, how do you prove that such a number as $2^{1/7}$ exists?

Comment: @Saulspatz and peter, hmm I didn't know you needed calculus for construction of these numbs

Comment: With respect to the comment of @saulspatz, once you accept $x^{(1/n)} ~: ~x\in \Bbb{R^+}, n \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}}~$ as a known value, it is game over.  This gives you $x^{(p/q)}, ~p,q \in \Bbb{Z}, q \neq 0.~$  Then, you simply attack (for example) $x^{\sqrt{2}}~$ as the limit of $x^{(14/10)}, ~x^{(141/100)}, ~x^{(1414/1000)}, \cdots$.

Comment: You can say that $2^{1/7}$ is the positive solution to $x^7=2$, but how do we know there is such a solution?  What about a number like $\pi^\pi$?  What does that even mean?  I don't know how to address that without concepts from calculus.

Comment: "No functions allowed!" But $x\mapsto x^2$ is a function. How are we ever going to evaluate $x^{1/2}$ without it?

Comment: I agree with @saulspatz . Calculus is the way to go

Comment: Although I could easily be mistaken, I find myself disagreeing with @saulspatz.  I do not believe that 500 years ago, the concept of $\pi^{\pi}$ was regarded as meaningless.  I speculate that using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to define the limit of a sequence preceded Calculus, and that Calculus involved the overhaul/formalization of such a concept.

Comment: Hmm, I mean functions are natural but I think so it may be possible to evaluate without @Arthur

Comment: @Buraian I don't think it is. I think you can avoid _mentioning_ functions, but I don't think you can avoid _using_ them, under the hood

Comment: As you say, we commonly learn square roots and a few other simple cases long before calculus but quite informally.  At this level, we just trust that they exist and don't request formal definitions.  Later, in more serious maths, we want these formal definitions and proofs of existence.

Comment: @user2661923 Then at least show that $\pi^{\pi}$ makes sense and that it exists without the tools mentioned in the post. But note that we are not allowed to use limits or numerical methods since this already includes using calculus.

Comment: @Peter You raise a key point.  Although the modern use of limits does involve Calculus (AKA Real Analysis), Calculus is only 400 some odd years old (or less) and the **crude** use of limits has been around since Archimedes.  This is the point of my previous comment.  In other words, 500 years ago, was the expression $\pi^{\pi}$ regarded as meaningless?  Since Archimedes, $\pi$ was regarded as a meaningful expression.  Therefore, a number such as $2^{\pi}$ would be regarded as meaningful, using the informal (perhaps invalid) pioneering notions of a limit.  Then, $\pi^{\pi}$ also makes sense.

Comment: @user2661923 I really doubt a number like $\pi^\pi$ were even considered in $1521$, and I'm sure no one could have computed it.  That about $100$ years before the invention of logarithms.

Comment: @saulspatz I certainly agree that no one could have computed it.  I also agree that such an expression wouldn't have been attacked unless it had facilitated solving a problem considered pertinent at the time.  However, based on Archimedes work, I don't see any impediment to a 1521 mathematician *conceptualizing* $\pi^{\pi}$ as the limit of the sequence of $$3^{(1/3)}, \left[\frac{31}{10}\right]^{(31/10)}, \left[\frac{314}{100}\right]^{(314/100)},  \cdots $$

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry, but saulspatz's arguments convince me more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid calculus/analysis, because as a very simple example, there is no rational number $\xi$ such that $\xi^2=2$. So, if we want to write down something such as $\sqrt{2}$ or $2^{1/2}$, this already requires the notion of real numbers. The key difference between reals and rationals is the supremum property/completeness, so any proper discussion of surds (such as the existence of square roots/$n^{th}$ roots etc) must invoke concepts from analysis.

What we can do (and this is still obviously not perfect) is take a few leaps of faith and try the most naive thing. It's easily proved that for $n\in\Bbb{N}$, the function $x\mapsto x^n$ defined on the positive reals (putting aside questions of how one would define this when this is literally the starting point of real analysis) is strictly increasing. So, for example if I were to  guess what $\xi:=2^{1/5}$ is (again putting aside issues of proving existence), I'd say that $(1.1)^5=1.61051$ and $(1.2)^5=2.48832$, so $\xi$ if it exists must satisfy $1.1<\xi<1.2$. Next, you make further guesses to what the next few decimals ought to be, for example $1.15^5=2.0113571875$ while $1.14^5=1.9254145824$, so we now also guess that $1.14<\xi<1.15$. Next, you can see (after lots of trial and error) that $1.148^5=1.99392785429$ but $1.149^5=2.00262735178$, so we now find $1.148<\xi<1.149$, and you can keep going like this. Thus far I have found basic decimal approximations:

- $\xi_1=1.1$
- $\xi_2=1.14$
- $\xi_3=1.148$

and we can keep going like this to figure out $\xi_n$ for all $n$. Then, $\xi_n$ will be the $n^{th}$ decimal approximation to $2^{1/5}$ (whatever this as-yet possibly non-existent beast is). We need the intermediate value theorem to justify that this approach yields the right answer.

Now, the very symbol $a^b$ with $a>0$ and $b\in\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ just cannot be defined without any notions from analysis. But if we were to play heuristics, then we'd first approximate $b$ by a sequence of rational numbers $\{b_1,b_2,\dots\}$, and then we compute $a^{b_k}$ (here since the exponent is rational, we can use the above approach for calculating it, to whatever accuracy you desire) and then you hope for the best that $a^b$ is well approximated by $a^{b_k}$.

You might object that I'm using the limit concept from analysis/calculus, but I'm sure such ideas were not unfamiliar to people in the past. Also, I should mention that without more precise tools from analysis, such a calculational procedure is just way too tedious (unless you only want $1$ or $2$ decimals), and we cannot even quantify how good our approximations are.

So, long story short, trial and error and pray (that the intermediate value theorem is right). I'm afraid this is the best answer I can provide.

Comment: Beating a dead horse (re my comments following the original question), your answer focuses on ensuring that the method used is **valid**.  Concerning the OP's posting, what about **invalid** methods that might be used to *conceptualize* the evaluation of a math expression.  My question still stands: in 1521, was $\pi^{\pi}$ considered a meaningless expression?

Comment: @user2661923 OP asks about $2^{1/4}$ (which I mistakenly read as $2^{1/5}$ for some reason), and I explain the most naive approach to calculating that. Similar story with $a^b$. I disagree that my answer focuses on ensuring validity, for the case of a rational exponent, I've provided a completely reasonable approach for calculating (and it turns out to be a correct approach because of the intermediate value theorem). With $a^b$, the computational procedure is the same.

Comment: Also, this tedious nature shouldn't be a surprise to anyone. This is just one of the simplest examples of where dealing with the inverse ($n^{th}$ roots) of a given function is MUCH harder than dealing with the original function itself (raising to $n^{th}$ power). Trying to limit the tools available only increases the difficulty of working with such inverse functions.